# получить точки полигонов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть карта https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCCKACPY

Я делаю страничку расчёта стоимости доставки, где понадобится определять, входит ли тока в какой-нибудь из этих полигонов.
Для начала надо вытащить их точки, наверное. Как это сделать?
Понадобится ли мне api-key?
Имеет ли значение, что эту карту создавал не я?
В идеале, чтобы при редактировании карты не пришлось что-то переписывать.

Answer (score 1):

Указанная карта создана в конструкторе карт.

Если вы владелец аккаунта, где эта карта создана, вы сможете как экспортировать все точки объектов (полигонов), так и редактировать эти объекты на карте. В противном случае эти возможности вам недоступны.

Проверить вхождение точки в полигон инструментами конструктора карт нельзя. Вам подойдет инструментарий JS API. В документации есть [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones) реализации такой задачи.